# Remove all but URL-s from XML files

Tags: notepad++, powershell, regex, xml

So i have a XML with bunch of links. What i want is to remove everything that is not an URL.
For example currently it looks something like this:

```
<update extract="1">
            <kb>KB2276594</kb>
            <date>2011/01/18</date>
            <size>348 KB</size>
            <category>Hotfix</category>
            <name>Windows6.1-KB2276594-x64.msu</name>
            <description>"Error – Sent to Printer" error when you try to send a large print job to a Web Services for Devices-based printer in Windows Server 2008 R2 or in Windows 7</description>
            <url>http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Windows%207/Windows%20Server2008%20R2%20SP1/sp2/Fix354908/7600/free/427003_intl_x64_zip.exe</url>
        </update>
```

What i want as a result is a clean XML file with URL-s in a row (preserving their order is not important). Like this:

```
http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Windows%207/Windows%20Server2008%20R2%20SP1/sp2/Fix354908/7600/free/427003_intl_x64_zip.exe
http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/.Net%20Framework%202.0%20–%20Win7%20SP1,%20Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%20SP1%20(CBS)/sp2/DevDiv947612/50727.5661/free/430877_intl_x64_zip.exe
```

And then copy the resulting URL's to clipboard all at once. This is on Windows 7 x64. Command Promt, Powershell v3 and Notepad++ regex methods are acceptable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the XML Tools plugin for Notepad++. Notepad++ will download and install it from the download manager under Plugins -> Plugin Manager.

It can evaluate XPaths and generate a list that you can copy/paste into Excel/Open Office where all of your URL's are in one column.

I used your XML snippet as an example, made multiple entries with different URL's, and put them all in a "test" element.  Clicked into one of the URL nodes, then used Plugins -> XML Tools -> Current XML Path (this copies the expression), then Plugins -> XML Tools -> Evaluate XPath Expression, pasted in the expression, clicked Evaluate, and the data was there to copy to excel.

[image]

Comment: Yep that's what i needed and it worked just fine. I always have the mentioned plugin installed. Too bad i cant turn this into a macro in N++ and that the result in clipboard includes some extra characters. But these are minor things i can work around. Thanks and marked as answer.

Comment: @TMRW I thought I could figure out how to specify the value at each URL node with the XPath, but I couldn't crack a way, so there's the extra Excel step. Glad it will work though!

Answer (score 2):

Regex is bad for parsing XML.

Powershell can can parse XML with something like this:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content {your_xml_file.xml}
$xml.xpath.to.update | Select-Object -Property url
```

Since you didn't post the full XML, it's hard to say what the xpath.to.update is, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Why the curly brackets?